# How to join two lists in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

We have two lists:

```
val a:List[(String, Int, Int)] = List(("apple", 3, 25),("orange", 4, 47))

val b:List[(String, String)] = List(("mango", "25"),("orange", "50"))
```

Which is the best method to Join a and b to get:

```
val c : List[(String, Int, Int, String)] = List(("orange", 4, 47, "50"))
```

Comment: Have you tried: 1. map to map 2. join maps

Comment: Didn't try join maps.

Comment: can you update your code to actually compile in scala?

Comment: When asking a question, please do mind to give a code that compiles and clearly shows your intentions. From the snippet above it's hard to say wether you actually have a `Map` or a `List`

Comment: @Łukasz Updated with working code.

Comment: @4lex1v Updated with working code.

Comment: `c : List[String, Int, String]` is not a valid Scala `List`. A [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) has a single type parameter, i.e. noting each element's type, whereas you've provided 3.

Comment: List[String, Int, String] is not valid, but List[(String, Int, String)] is valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the first list and lookup the values of the second list in a map `mb`. The `.flatMap` makes the entry dissappear, if the `.get` returns `None`.

```
 val mb = b.toMap

 a.flatMap{case (ka,va,vva) => mb.get(ka).map(vb => (ka,va,vva,vb))}
```

Comment: @GKVM See the REPL-session I added. It does exactly what you are asking for. Unless you didn't give all required specifications, of course. Like to elaborate what's wrong?

Comment: @GKVM I've updated my code. But the old answer was correct for the old question, and the answer to the updated question was trivially derivable from the old answer. You broke two rules for SO: 1) don't change the question to something different, and 2) ask a minimal/most general question. The old question was more general and contained the core of the problem you faced; it was better.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the lists, and then group them by the first element of your tuple:

```
val groupedTuples: Map[String, List[(String, String)]] = (a ++ b).groupBy(_._1)
val c: Map[String, List[String]] =  groupedTuples.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

This will result in

```
Map(mango -> List(25), orange -> List(4, 50), apple -> List(3))
```

Comment: That isn't the OP's desired output. Also, it does something different if there are duplicate keys in either list.